# Highcharts Sync charts vertically

Tags: charts, highcharts, synchronization

I am trying to build synchronous charts as on this link https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts, but switch x and y-axis to view charts as in the picture below:

[image]

How it could be done? Any help much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable `inverted` property for charts and set right dimensions for containers, for example:

JS:

```
chart: {
    inverted: true
}
```

CSS:

```
.chart {
    width: 33%;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cdok7w0L/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.inverted